# Where is the best documentation of Microsoft Excel Biff format

Tags: excel, openoffice.org

I am looking for the best documentation of Microsoft Excel's file format - 1997 - > 2003.
I am not looking for ooxml.
What is the best resource on the web?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Published by Microsoft :

Good intro :
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat(xls)Specification.pdf

Complete MSDN pdf file : [http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/[MS-XLS].pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/%5BMS-XLS%5D.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Here:

http://www.microsoft.com/interop/docs/OfficeBinaryFormats.mspx